# "split it down" meaning in business context

Tags: particle-shift

I came across this in the Business Advantage listening.
Two parties, Y being the manufacturer and X the distributor, are discussing the issue of whose responsibility stockouts are. Here is the dialogue:

> A: I'm not happy with the description of "X stock out". That means that we at X will be responsible for any stock out - but that will not show if the market information from you at Y has provided the wrong figures for production.
>
> B: What we used to do at Y head office was we used to have a number of markets out of stock and then we used to split it down.

Does B mean they would direct the existing goods to those several out-of-stock markets? or does this have to do with shares and equities, of which I have no understanding whatsoever? What does B refer to as 'it'? the number? the whole situation?

Comment: Does "stock" here mean a financial product or a commodity that is out of stock?

Comment: I'm no economist or business person and don't really know what a financial product is (a commodity, I believe, is just a manufactured product that can be bought and sold, right?) From the task's explanation of the situation, it being 'X will start to produce and distribute Y's products', I suppose it's the latter. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @PhiKay I think he may have been thinking of something like a stock split, which is appropriate for a financial product but not physical products.